# Topological Space Intuition

Tags: general-topology, intuition

I gained some insight recently when I read an intuitive explanation for what "rich" topologies actually model.  It said, basically, that a rich enough topology (say, a Hausdorff one) is a model for "zooming in" indefinitely.

Of course, given the conventions of the subject, I have to assume that a "zoom in" operation would be given by "pointing" at a neighborhood inside the "current" open set.

So what happens if we treat the closed sets as our primary objects?  I have in mind the diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\tau @>\cap_X>> \tau\\
@VV'V @VV'V\\
\nu @>\cup_{X'}>> \nu
\end{CD}
$$

where $\tau$ is a topological space, and $\nu$ is a realization of the equivalent topology defined in terms of closed sets.  Does the $\cup_{X'}$ operation correspond, at least intuitively, to zooming out?

Does this intuition extend or generalize for zero-dimensional spaces -- i.e., topologies where every element of $\tau$ is both closed and open?

Comment: A topology where every set is both closed and open is called a *discrete topology*.  This is different from a zero-dimensional topology.  For example, the Cantor set is zero-dimensional but not discrete.

Comment: I did mean to refer to zero-dimensional spaces, but I was ambiguous.  Editing.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the terms *totally disconnected*, *zero-dimensional*, and *discrete*.  If every element of the space is both closed and open, the space is discrete.  It sounds like you want to describe a totally disconnected space, in which every element is a connected component.